# Given a set of sets of points, can one determine if a straight line exists that intercepts through a point in each set, and the line's formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I have a problem where I have a set of sets of points. I need to determine if I can make a straight line that intercepts through one point in each set of points and the formula of that line.

Is there a mathematical way to do this? Maybe with using some trial and error method?

Edit: The points are (x,y) coordinates. You can consider these points to be given.

For example, I can have a straight line intercepting (2,1)(3,2)(4,3) but cannot for the case of (2,1)(3,2)(4,3.5).

.

Comment: Are you familiar with Euclid's first axiom?

Comment: What kind of points are these? Where are they taken from? Without further information it isn't really possible to answer, although you should note that in the most general case such a line doesn't even exist.

Comment: Needed to add this: The points are (x,y) coordinates. You can consider these points to be given.

For example, I can have a straight line intercepting (2,1)(3,2)(4,3) but cannot for the case of (2,1)(3,2)(4,3.5).

Comment: How are your points chosen? There is exactly one and only one line passing through any two given points in the Euclidean plane. This means that almost every triple of points *will not* lie on the same line, because almost every point in the plane doesn't lie on any give line.

Comment: Note that the input is a set of sets of points, increasing the possibility that we can have such a line. Assume the points are random, and ALL unique, regardless of whether they are or are not in the same set.

Comment: Actually, if the points were truly random then the probability that such a line exists is $0$ as long as there are more then two sets and $1$ if there are one or two sets (note that random points are almost certainly unique and the uniqueness assumption doesn't change the argument at all)... anyway, I hope that my answer is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider two points with coordinates $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$. Then the coordinates $(x,y)$ of any point on the line $L_{1,2}$ through $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ satisfy the equations
$$
\begin{cases}
x = x_1 + t (x_2 - x_1) \\
y = y_1 + t (y_2 - y_1)
\end{cases}
$$
which are called the *parametric equations* of $L_{1,2}$. You can get the *Cartesian equation* of $L_{1,2}$ by solving for $t$:
$$
y = y_1 + (x - x_1) \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}
$$
Moreover, a third point $(x_3,y_3)$ lies on $L_{1,2}$ if and only if
$$
\begin{cases}
x_3 = x_1 + t (x_2 - x_1) \\
y_3 = y_1 + t (y_2 - y_1)
\end{cases}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x_3 - x_1 = t (x_2 - x_1) \\
y_3 - y_1 = t (y_2 - y_1)
\end{cases}
$$
that is to say, if and only if
$$
\frac{x_3 - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{y_3 - y_1}{y_2 - y_1}
$$
i.e. if and only if the slope of $L_{1,2}$ and the slope of the line through $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ are the same. Note that to account for vertical lines it is better to check if
$$
(x_3 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1) = (x_2 - x_1)(y_3 - y_1)
$$

---

Indeed, this is apparent from the geometric picture, too. Note that here I'm going to assume that the coordinates of your points are real numbers, but that's just to fix ideas.

Fix a point $p$ in the plane. Then there is a $1:1$ correspondence between the lines through $p$ and the set $\Bbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, where to the vertical line corresponds the symbol $\infty$ and to every other line corresponds its slope.

Since the points $s,r,p$ are collinear (i.e. lie on the same line) if and only if the lines $L_{p,s} = \langle p,s \rangle$ and $L_{p,r} = \langle p,r \rangle$ coincide, it follows that $s,r,p$ are collinear if and only if the "numbers" corresponding to $L_{p,s}$ and $L_{p,r}$ are the same.

Comment: This helps! ALOT! THANKS!